# How can I combine LVM cache and writecache?

Tags: lvm, cache, caching

Can I attach both a cache (in modus Writethrough) as well as a writecache to a logical volume in LVM? If yes, how?

I am well able to attach a "normal" cache. But when trying to also add a writecache I fail.